# Crashes are not reporting if I'm using FirebaseCrashlytics with Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-crash-reporting

This is my application class

```
class App : MultiDexApplication() {
override fun onCreate() {
       FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(GoExceptionHandler(this))
       super.onCreate()
   }
}
```

& Here is ExceptionHandler

```
class GoExceptionHandler(val context: Context) : Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    override fun uncaughtException(p0: Thread, p1: Throwable) {
        class GoExceptionHandler(val context: Context) : Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    override fun uncaughtException(p0: Thread, p1: Throwable) {
        AmplitudeAnalyticsTracker.sendCrashEvent(p1.localizedMessage!!)
// Clearing Cache & data if crash occurrence more than 2 time
        if (LocalPreference.getCrashCount() >= 3) {  
            context.cacheDir.deleteRecursively()
            (context.getSystemService(MultiDexApplication.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
                    .clearApplicationUserData()
        } else {
            LocalPreference.setCrashCount()
        }
    }
}
    }
}
```

When I comment the `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(GoExceptionHandler(this))` then the crash is reporting proper in Crashlytic console but when I add this in to my APP class it's become nightmare & there is no crash report over firebase

Answer (score 0):

This is based upon the flawed business logic of your code (you're disabling the crash reporting); otherwise Crashlytics would be the **default** `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. If you still would like to report to Crashlytics, you'd need to log the `Exception` within method `uncaughtException()`:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(p1)
```

Comment: but then it will log exception like a non fatal exception.. no?

Comment: There is no such thing as a fatal or non fatal exception; there's only handled and unhandled. In this case one can instance an exception without throwing it, but this doesn't prevent one from still throwing it... see `try`, `catch` and `throw`.

Comment: in firebase console we have fatal and not fatal

Answer (score 0):

Crash reporting services such as Crashlytics typically use `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to capture and report crashes. There can be only one `UncaughtExceptionHandler` so if you set your own, it replaces any existing one.

To have both Crashlytics and your own handler active at the same time, make your own handler query the existing handler via `getUncaughtExceptionHandler()` and delegate crash handling to it by calling it yourself.